# SSIS: Accessing a network drive using a different username and password

Tags: ssis

Is there a way to connect to a network drive that requires a different username/password than the username/password of the user running the package?

I need to copy files from a remote server.  Right now I map the network drive in Windows Explorer then do I filesystem task.  However, eventually this package will be ran automatically, from a different machine, and will need to map the network drive on its own.  Is this possible?

Comment: Why can you not just give the necessary permissions to the user or process running the package? If you explain why you have that limitation, you might get a better answer. In the meantime, what about NET USE?

Comment: We are going to do run it as a user that has permissions.  The problem is that it is a mapped drive on an AS400 and we normally run all of our jobs with an account that has more than 10 characters and an underscore in the name--which is not supported on an AS400.  We were hoping, for consistency's sake, to run this job with the same account and just authenticate with the 400 on the other account...  But we are thinking that that isn't worth it so are probably going to just give up...

Answer (score 14):

You can use the Execute Process task with the "net use" command to create the mapped drive. Here's how the properties of the task should be set:

**Executable:** net

**Arguments:** use \Server\SomeShare YourPassword /user:Domain\YourUser

Any File System tasks following the Execute Process will be able to access the files.

**Alternative Method**

This [Sql Server Select Article](http://sqlserverselect.blogspot.com/2012/05/ssis-accessing-network-resources-on.html) covers the steps in details but the basics are:

1) Create a "Execute Process Task" to map the network drive (this maps to the z:)

```
Executable: cmd.exe
Arguments: /c "NET USE Z: "\\servername\shareddrivename" /user:mydomain\myusername mypassword"
```

2) Then run a "File System Task" to perform the copy.  Remember that the destination "Flat File Connection" *must* have "DelayValidation" set to True as z:\suchandsuch.csv won't exist at design time.

3) Finally, unmap the drive when you're done with another "Execute Process Task"

```
Executable: cmd.exe
Arguments: /c "NET USE Z: /delete"
```

Comment: Thanks @Valentino Vranken!  Your solution saved me, but I updated your answer to include a related article that I found after using your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Valentino works like a charm. Only add at end instruction /yes parameter `/c "NET USE Z: /delete /yes"` to force disconnect

Comment: I get error while i try to map network drive from command prompt. Error says, " The filename, directory, or the volume label syntax is incorrect"

Comment: Can this be done in a Stored Procedure with `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @myCmd;`?

Comment: This can indeed be done in a Stored Procedure, but just as for Execute Process, the task must finish; you must write 3 separate procedures, the second one using the mapped drive. Also, SQL Server can't perform database operations on the new drive, but you can move the file to a folder on the network first.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an FTP task to GET the files over to the local machine? Run SSIS on the local machine. When transferring using FTP in binary, its real fast. Just remember that the ROW delimter for SSIS should be LF, not CRLF, as binary FTp does not convert LF (unix) to CRLF (windows)

Answer (score 1):

You have to map the network drive, here's an example that I'm using now:

```
    profile = "false"
    landingPadDir = Dts.Variables("strLandingPadDir").Value.ToString
    resultsDir = Dts.Variables("strResultsDir").Value.ToString
    user = Dts.Variables("strUserName").Value.ToString
    pass = Dts.Variables("strPassword").Value.ToString
    driveLetter = Dts.Variables("strDriveLetter").Value.ToString

    objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    CheckDrive = objNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives()

    If CheckDrive.Count > 0 Then
        For intcount = 0 To CheckDrive.Count - 1 Step 2 'if drive is already mapped, then disconnect it
            If CheckDrive.Item(intcount) = driveLetter Then
                objNetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive(driveLetter)
            End If
        Next
    End If

    objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive(driveLetter, landingPadDir, profile, user, pass)
```

From There just use that driveLetter and access the file via the mapped drive.

I'm having one issue (which led me here) with a new script that accesses two share drives and performs some copy/move operations between the drives and I get an error from SSIS that says:

```
This network connection has files open or requests pending.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.LateBinding.InternalLateCall(Object o, Type objType, String name, Object[] args, String[] paramnames, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateCall(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, Boolean IgnoreReturn)
   at ScriptTask_3c0c366598174ec2b6a217c43470f581.ScriptMain.Main()
```

This is only on the "2nd run" of the process and if I run it a 3rd time it all works fine so I'm guessing the connection isn't being properly closed or it is not waiting for the copy/move to complete before moving forward or some such, but I'm unable to find a "close" or "flush" command that prevents this error.  If you have any solution, please let me know, but the above code should work for getting the drive mapped using your alternate credentials and allow you to access that share.

Zach

Comment: It's a variable that references and is used to access the object created by CreateObject("WScript.Network")

Answer (score 0):

To make the package more robust, you can do the following;

In the first Execute Process Task, set - FailTaskIfReturnCodeNotSuccessValue = False
This will let the package run if the last disconnect has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question but more recent versions of SQL Server with SSIS databases allow you to use a proxy to execute SQ Server jobs.

1. In SSMS Under Security<Credentials set up a credential in the database mapped to the AD account you want to use.
2. Under SQL Server Agent create a new proxy giving it the credential from step 1 and permissions to execute SSIS packages.
3. Under the SQL Server Agent jobs create a new job that executes your package
4. Select the step that executes the package and click EDIT. In the Run As dropdown select the Proxy you created in step 2