# configure username and password for already mapped UNC path in ssis using file system task.

Tags: ssis, filesystems, unc

I was refering this : [SSIS: Accessing a network drive using a different username and passoword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258716/ssis-accessing-a-network-drive-using-a-different-username-and-passoword)

But, here it seems that unc location is mapped runtime. My case is bit different, my unc location is already mapped and I just need to configure username and password in my configuration file.how can I do this in ssis package.

Note- I need to copy file to unc location.

Thanks.

Comment: Help me understand. The UNC is already mounted but you need to recreate it using a different user and password?

Comment: UNC is aleady mounted and each time i trys to connect, its asking username and password.So, i just wanted to put this in config file; and when my job starts it will be read username and password from config file.I'm using file stystem task in SSIS to upload the files.

Answer (score 1):

Each time the system is rebooted, the mapped drive needs to be connected again with the credentials if these were not saved. unfortunately we dont have so called cleaner approach by just reusing the existing mapped drive just by passing credentials(actually this is in disconnected mode after reboot)

Either you have to run batch file with net use /DELETE option to remove the existing mapped drive and recreate the mapped drived with credential or with net use with the /SAVECRED option to re-use the passowd credentials, this batch needs to be linked to startup window to retain the connection after reboot.

sample batch script

```
@echo off
net use z: /delete
net use z: \\server\share /USER:MYCOMPUTER\UserID password
exit
```

Or go to Command Prompt, run

> net use z: \\server\share /savecred /p:yes

spefify the credential, it should retain the credential after reboot

Or add the credentials by opening Start → Run → control > userpasswords2 → Advanced → Manage Passwords on Windows XP and later.

Or map the network drive as suggested in [SSIS: Accessing a network drive using a different username and passoword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258716/ssis-accessing-a-network-drive-using-a-different-username-and-passoword?lq=1)