# SSIS create file on network drive

Tags: c#, file-io, ssis, network-drive

I'm trying to create a SSIS package, which creates a file based on a sql query which should be uploaded to a network drive (I'm already using the UNC path).
It works all fine when I execute the package from the data solution, but when I try to execute it via a process that runs with the localsystem account, it doesn't work because the localsystem account doesn't have enough permissions to create the file.

Is there another possibility how to achieve this?
I was able to do it by mapping the network drive in a execute process task but that's not really a solution I can accept, because I have to store the credential information in the arguments of the task...

Do you know of any other way how to achieve this?
Maybe with a ftp task?

Thanks in advance

Comment: don't run it as local system. How exactly are you executing it? If it's in SQL Agent you can set up credentials and proxies. If it's in some other tool tell us what it is and we may be able to help.

Comment: You might consider Script Task .. [SSIS Example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/323c6265-13fe-4c99-ab70-746c195d380b/access-mapped-network-drive-using-file-system-task-in-ssis-package?forum=sqlintegrationservices). The following example is not using SSIS but the logic may be used [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258716/ssis-accessing-a-network-drive-using-a-different-username-and-passoword)

Answer (score 1):

Do you launch the package from an SQL Agent job?
If so, you need to create a proxy account that has permissions on the network drive to create files, like in this link:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/